# Is it valid to submit an iPhone app as Universal without any code changes?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I have a simple iPhone app, mostly table views, map views and other standard stuff. When I change the project settings to make it universal, everything works fine after a few small tweaks. So the iPad version looks just as a big iPhone app.

Definitely, the app will look better if I use some split views, pop-ups and generally rework the UI to look better on the iPad. But I wonder - will Apple review team accept a universal app that is basically just an enlarged version of the iPhone app?

Comment: Doesn't seem advisable if your app in iPad would have very little data and plenty of whitespace. It's better to rethink your approach for the iPad separately as well and then make a universal app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Btw, I've submitted the app without any changes, and it was accepted without any problems.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you explain what's changed when you do an update submission (e.g. "now with an iPad-friendly User Interface!"), Apple *should* accept your update no problem.

Answer (score 2):

What are you afraid of? That Apple would give you a reason for rejection? Just do it, and if you get feedback make the necessary changes. Even if Apple is control freak #1 and a humbling power monster megacorp, I'd be much more worried about it being published and USERS not approving it. :)

Answer (score 0):

iPad users can download and run your iPhone app just the way it is and get the same results either way.  From any non-marketing point of view, what would be the advantage to calling it 'Universal' with no changes?

Comment: The 2x upscaled iPhone version doesn't look very well because the resolution is lower, text is not as crisp. And I think some people just don't like to use the iPhone version on the iPad.